# Swaping values of two lists based on given index

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have a list which consists out of two numpy arrays, the first one telling the index of a value and the second containing the belonging value itself. It looks a little like this:

```
x_glob = [[0, 2], [85, 30]]
```

A function is now receiving the following input:

```
x = [-10, 0, 77, 54]
```

My goal is to swap the values of x with the values from x_glob based on the given index array from x_glob. This example should result in something like this:

```
x_new = [85, 0, 30, 54]
```

I do have a solution using a loop. But I am pretty sure there is a way in python to solve this issue more efficient and elegant.

Thank you!

Comment: How does your loop-solution look like?

Answer (score 3):

[**`NumPy`** arrays may be indexed with other arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays), which makes this replacement trivial.

All you need to do is index your second array with `x_glob[0]`, and then assign `x_glob[1]`

```
x[x_glob[0]] = x_glob[1]
```

To see *how* this works, just look at the result of the indexing:

```
>>> x[x_glob[0]]
array([-10,  77])
```

The result is an array containing the two values that we need to replace, which we then replace with another `numpy` array, `x_glob[1]`, to achieve the desired result.

---

```
>>> x_glob = np.array([[0, 2], [85, 30]])
>>> x = np.array([-10, 0, 77, 54])
>>> x[x_glob[0]] = x_glob[1]
>>> x
array([85,  0, 30, 54])
```

Answer (score 2):

For a non-`numpy` solution, you could create a `dict` mapping the indices from `x_glob` to the respective values and then use a list comprehension with that dict's `get` method:

```
>>> x_glob = [[0, 2], [85, 30]]
>>> x = [-10, 0, 77, 54]
>>> d = dict(zip(*x_glob))
>>> [d.get(i, n) for i, n in enumerate(x)]
[85, 0, 30, 54]
```

Or using `map` with multiple parameter lists (or without `zip` using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)):

```
>>> list(map(d.get, *zip(*enumerate(x))))
[85, 0, 30, 54]
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution also uses `for` loop, but it's pretty short and elegant (I think), works in place and is effective as it does not have to iterate through full x array, just through list of globs:

```
for k,v in zip(*x_glob):
    x[k] = v
```

Comment: You could also use `for k, v in zip(...`